# Split a very long Cypress test

Tags: forms, split, wizard

I need to split a test case, I have a forms that are composed of 6 different forms, and every forms need to fil in. My question is if is possible to that?
Cypress reload the site if i using "it" and all the data that I have filed in disappear.

Comment: Maybe this blog post from Cypress is what you need: [Split a very long Cypress test into shorter ones using App Actions](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/10/29/split-a-very-long-cypress-test-into-shorter-ones-using-app-actions/)